# Android - methods to alert a user?

Tags: android

I have an android application that gets data from the web such as an event title, location, date and time. I'd like to alert the user when it is time for the event. I've tried using the calendar API but that seems to be quite vague and unsupported by android. Are there any other ways to alert a user when there is an upcoming event based on the date and time I supply? Being able to set an alarm or something would do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Status bar notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) or [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) would be the classic way.  Read:

**Notifying the User**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html

Comment: Just looking at the notification manager now - this line of code: Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
What am I supposed to put in MyClass.class? All I want to do is pass in a few values and when it is time, alert the user.. like a text message or something. My app need not be running.

Comment: you should put the name of class from which you will set the values

Comment: @Mark Olsen - The intent is what should happen when the user wants more info about the notification. In your case, it would seem natural to take them to the web page that provides more info about the upcoming event.  Here's an example that shows using a notification with a web intent (shown under "Here is the code that will work"): http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=3506&ownerUserId=satya

Answer (score 0):

There are notifications started by a service so your application doesn't need to be running. Inside your Activity you can use Toasts or Dialogs.

Regarding your kind of information you want to provide I recommend to use a notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule notification using the AlarmManager. And notification can be created using NotificationManager.

You can perform the post of notification in an intent service. Schedule the intent that starts your IntentService with AlarmManager and than inplement the post in onHandleIntent() method. Notification body parameters can be passed as intent extras to you service.